How to find the asymptotic envelope of a function?
Context
I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the envelope of a given function.
Unless I missed it, it would be of interest to have a Mathematica function which
when given
AsymptoticEnvelope[f[x], x -> Infinity]

would return the leading order of the envelope?
Question

Any idea how to write as generic a function to achieve this goal?

I would like to know (at least) what is the power-law behaviour of the function which is always above/below that function, touching the function, and ideally have an approximate function involving simpler functions which matches the large scale behaviour?
For instance, for BesselJ[n,x] it should return
 Sqrt[2/Pi/x] Cos[x-n Pi/2 -Pi/4]

or at least
  Sqrt[2/Pi/x]

Example
To be concrete, I am interested in the large k behaviour of the function
h[k_]=(R^2*(2*k*R*BesselJ[1, k*R] - 
    Pi*BesselJ[1, k*R]*StruveH[0, k*R] + 
    Pi*BesselJ[0, k*R]*StruveH[1, k*R])^2)/
 (4*k^4)

Which behaves like (for R=1,2,3,4)

For context, h[k_] is defined by
h[k_] = HankelTransform[UnitStep[(R - r)] r, r, k] // 
    FunctionExpand // 
 Simplify[#, Assumptions -> R > 0] &; tt *= tt;

Comment
This nice question/answer addresses the issue of finding the envelope via Hilbert transform, but it seems to work only for sums of trigonomeric functions.
I understand it's probably mathematically challenging to get a generic function.
May be a possible pragmatic method would be to use Discrete Hilbert Transform in Log space?

The Series command of 14.0 on Windows 10 produces the required answer for BesselJ[n,x]
Series[BesselJ[n, x], {x, Infinity, 0}] // Normal


(Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Cos[1/4 (1 + 2 n) \[Pi] - x])/Sqrt[x]

In view of it, I think
Series[(R^2*(2*k*R*BesselJ[1, k*R] - 
Pi*BesselJ[1, k*R]*StruveH[0, k*R] + 
Pi*BesselJ[0, k*R]*StruveH[1, k*R])^2)/(4*k^4), {k, Infinity,3}, Assumptions -> R > 0] // Normal


(2 R^3 Cos[\[Pi]/4 + k R]^2)/(k^3 \[Pi])

does the job too.

Thanks! Seems to do the job!

Would it make sense to try and automate the choice of 3 that you made in the second example? AsymptoticEnvelope would be a function which chooses the first value which returns a non zero value ?

Let a = Asymptotic[(R^2*(2*k*R*BesselJ[1, k*R] -            Pi*BesselJ[1, k*R]*StruveH[0, k*R] +            Pi*BesselJ[0, k*R]*StruveH[1, k*R])^2)/(4*k^4),      k -> Infinity, SeriesTermGoal -> 4, Assumptions -> R > 0] //     Simplify ; and b = Series[(R^2*(2*k*R*BesselJ[1, k*R] -            Pi*BesselJ[1, k*R]*StruveH[0, k*R] +            Pi*BesselJ[0, k*R]*StruveH[1, k*R])^2)/(4*k^4), {k,       Infinity, 4}, Assumptions -> R > 0] // Normal;. ThenSimplify[a-b] results in 0.

oops you are right! my bad

The following encapsulating function would find the order by itself (admittedly slow) AsymptoticEnvelope[expr_, x_ -> lim_] := Module[{t1},   Catch@Table[     t1 = Series[expr, {x, lim, n}, Assumptions -> R > 0] // Normal;     If[Length[t1] > 0, Throw[t1]],     {n, 1, 10}]]

A spot on the Sun: sometimes Series returns the input. I think   the game is not worth the candle.
